# Postgres JSONB Select by VersionNumber, return only the latest

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Sample Data:

```
VersionNumber Label
------------- ------
1             Apple
2             Apple
3             Apple
1             Orange
```

**What i like to do:**

I like it to return just 3, Apple and 1, Orange

```
select elem -> 'VersionNumber' as VersionNumber, elem-> 'Label' as Label
  from transaction o , lateral jsonb_array_elements(fruits -> 'records') elem
 group by VersionNumber, Label
```

I tried the above, but I am not sure how to get only the latest VersionNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, seems you have a jsonb type column `fruits` within the table as

```
{ "records": [ 
             { "VersionNumber": 1, "Label": "Apple" },
             { "VersionNumber": 2, "Label": "Apple" },
             { "VersionNumber": 3, "Label": "Apple" },
             { "VersionNumber": 1, "Label": "Orange" }
        ] }
```

Then, you're at the half way. Just a windows analytic function (such as `RANK()`) needed due to partitioned by `Labels` column while descendingly ordered by `VersionNumber` column as

```
SELECT VersionNumber, Label 
  FROM
  (
   SELECT elem -> 'VersionNumber' as VersionNumber, elem->> 'Label' as Label,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY elem-> 'Label'
                       ORDER BY elem-> 'Label', elem -> 'VersionNumber' DESC) AS rnk
     FROM transaction 
     JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(fruits -> 'records') elem
       ON TRUE
   ) q
  WHERE q.rnk = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=29e0dec1e0d7c38728ab35b2a341e774)</kbd>